# catch event on Power button + home key press together on Ios device

Tags: ios, xcode, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi

I am wondering to know, is there is any private framework for catch the event for Power button + home key press together for switch off ios device. when user press these buttons together instead of power off, I need to open another application or open the camera something like this. I know this is rubbish idea.. but I don't have any other options. this is my client requirement.

Because he is going to use Iron panels for ios device. the only way to power off is press power button and home key together. so , when the person press those button together, ios device wants to open a app like iGotya , find my device and so on. we know, Apple never accepts this, it's gonna to be a jailbreak app. we know this well. please some one kindly guide me in this and give me some tutorial on this. I am quite new to IOS development. kindly help me. thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but which iOS device has a removable battery?

Comment: I found few applications in Internet such as 【TurnOffButton】 and so on. these applications configure Power button press. when we press power button it can open message, browser and so on. I would like to know, how can I catch power button press event alone. how can I configure power button press event. ? what kind of framework can I use for this ?

Comment: how can I get power button pressing event alone. I found some applications in Internet, they just open some app when we press power button. how can I do this. what kind of framework can I use. ?